# How should I do Exception on Laravel5 Resource Controller?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I know Laravel5 Resource method will work like this.

TestControler@index /aa
TestControler@edit /aa/{aa}/edit
..

It's good to work if integer have been inserted.
/aa/1/edit -> work

But it will broken if string is coming.
/aa/aa/edit -> SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation ..

So I wanna ask you the question is how should I allow request url thats integer only?

where should I write, route.php or Controller?
and how to abort 404 if string is coming.
any idea?

Comment: _Think_ this might be what you're talking about: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Comment: That's it!! It's great work for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Shall I put that into an answer so you can accept it for anyone else that comes across this question?

Comment: sure man! I must read document really lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to reply, Finally It works great.

But I wanna add this to my post.

Where method will work when I write 'standard' routing like this.

```
Route::get('/aa/{aa}/edit','TestsController@delete')->name('aa.edit')->where('aa','[0-9]+'); // works great!
```

But that's not work if I write 'RESTful' routing like this.

```
Route::resource('/aa', 'TestsController')->where('aa','[0-9]+'); // not work!
```

So I wrote this to app/route.php, It works very fine.

```
Route::pattern('aa', '\d+');
Route::get('/aa/{aa}/delete','TestsController@delete')->name('aa.delete')->where('aa','[0-9]+');
Route::resource('/aa', 'TestsController')->where('aa','[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

When working with Laravel's router, for any parameter you add to a URI definition (such as `{id}`), you can add a regex constraint. The constraint will take the variable value and test to see if the regex matches the value. If the regex fails, then the route will not be selected.

You do this using the `where()` method on the route and passing an associative array where the keys correspond to the variables in the URI, and the values are regexes to match. You can add constraints to as many variables in a route's URI as you like.

For example, if you wanted to constrain the id value in your URI to just numbers, you could do something like this:

```
Route::get("users/{id}", "Users@getUser")->where(["id" => "[0-9]+"]);
```

The documentation for this feature states:

> You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained

See more examples in the documentation available here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints